# Filter/sort column when using foreign key in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

In Yii2, I have generated a `model/view/controller` for table. The `view/index.php` shows:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'username',
        'type',
        'clientid',//a foreign key to the table client          

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

But of course, I want to show a name from the client, not the clientid. That's easy: Instead of `'clientid'`, I have to write `'client.name'`, and it's fixed. However, I can't sort or filter the column anymore.

How do I sort/filter the column referencing another table?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following code in `GridView`

```
[
   'attribute' => 'clientid',
   'value' => 'client.name',
]
```

And another code add in search model and also put `clientid` attribute in `safe` like as

```
public function rules()
{
        return [
            ['clientid', 'safe'],
        ];
}
```

And add below code in `search()` function.

```
$query->joinWith(['client(relation_name)']);

....

$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'client.name (table_name.field_name)', $this->clientid]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to declaration $client in search model. It worked for me.

in base Model :

```
 public function getClient()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Client::className(), ['id' => 'clientid']);
}
```

in search Model:

```
public $client; 

public function rules()
{

    parent::rules();
    return array_merge(
        [
            [['client', ], 'safe'],
        ]
    );
}
```

in search function:

```
$query->joinWith('client');
$query->andFilterWhere([
        'client_id' => $this->client_id,
->andFilterWhere(['like', 'client.name', $this->client]);
```

in view:

```
[
  'attribute' => 'client',
  'label' => 'client name',
  'value' => 'client.name',
]
```

I hope this will help you.

This is the source :http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/